# is there a way to do it quickly?

Tags: 3d, blender

before [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX9cY.jpg)

after [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoO51.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmF5x.jpg)

How to quickly ideally rotate the second plane? so that two planes meet.

Additional images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed5Qh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTDy4.png)

important picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GyRn.png)

I want to cut out the blue part from the round metal

I have already done this, but in a long way, I often need to do such things.
I want to learn how to quickly apply a 3d shape to a plane.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Am I having a hard time coming up with a specific question? so I gave an example with pictures

Comment: this is a very important question, i will often have to use this trick

Comment: It is hard to interpret the images almost without any context. Please consider addressing the following questions for the community to understand the question better. What is the problem? What is each of these images for? What is your current solution (a minimal reproducible example, if there is any)? Which programming language or application are you using? How are the planes represented (e.g., vertices)?

Comment: @DilaraGokay I added a question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on the Blender Stack Exchange: https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @datenwolf 
Thanks for the info, I'll try asking the question there too.

Comment: @datenwolf [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264125/is-there-a-way-to-do-it-quickly)